# Rectangular approximation of contours

Tags: opencv, contour

After some color detection, binary thresholding, and using cvFindContours() and drawing the contours and detected blue rectangle on the image I have:

[image]

My problem is to some simple collision avoidance (the blue rectangle in the center cannot hit the red "walls"). It would be helpful for my purposes to have the red wall contours be approximated as with rectangles. However, using a simple cvBoundingRect and drawing red rectangles around the white contours I get:

[image]

The edges are a little cropped off, but you may get the idea of what we would expect using a bounding rectangle for the contours, as the entire contour is used for the approximation of the bounding rectangle and hence the large overlapping rectangles. What I would like to have is the wall contours be divided into multiple bounding  rectangles, such as the the left wall be approximated as one rectangle, the right wall, the forward wall, etc...as in my illustrative rendition below:

[image]

Any help in doing so would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Detecting lines (typically Hough, RANSAC) together with some other information you have about the problem should be enough, maybe even overkill. For instance, starting with the below image at left, we get the below image at right.

[image] [image]

But if you have the above image at left (which you should have already), the problem is already solved. Just draw both internal and external contours of the walls and you are set.

Comment: I have looked into using cvHoughLines2 before but my lack of experience with the various parameters listed here:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/feature_detection.html
led me to look into other solutions. For example, how did you obtain the image on the right? (rho=?, theta=?, etc.)

Comment: I didn't use OpenCV for that, but doing so I managed to obtain http://i.imgur.com/hUCFgsk.png. The `rho` and `theta` parameters define the resolution of the accumulator in the Hough space, typical values are, respectively, `1` and `pi/180` (radians), but `rho` doesn't need to be in the integer domain and in fact I've used `rho = 0.1` to obtain this result. I set `threshold = 60` too. I didn't use probabilistic Hough, but you could try it too.

Comment: Okay i studied how hough transform works and seems to be a good method for detecting lines. I probably should have mentioned I am attempting to process this in real time and continue detecting the walls as the blue rectangle remains in the same place in the image but the walls move. I believe I have to now set the parameters to account for the added noise between each frame. Is there a good approach to doing so or is trial and error common in this case?

Comment: @salgarcia you will likely find papers that deal with this kind of problem, but I don't have one in my mind to point out. But, before continuing on Hough Transform and related methods, first make sure the image shown at left isn't enough. It is clearly showing the wall boundaries, isn't that fine already ?